# how to create and save edittext from alert?

Tags: java, android

I am still trying to learn java android so I am sure this is easy but I am trying to save the text from an alert started from an onclicklistener using the edit text to rename a button (tabButton). Do I have to create a seperate layout or will this work? I am getting an error at

```
 final EditText input = new EditText(this);
```

Like I said I am still learning so a good explanation is appreciated. Here is my src so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Tab buttons controlled
        final Button getTabButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        getTabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Tab1 button was clicked.
                alert.setTitle("Title");
                alert.setMessage("Message");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Editable tabname = input.getText();
                        // Do something with value!
                        tabname =

                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        getTabButton.settext(input.getText().toString());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button getTabButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getTabButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        getTabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Title");
                alert.setMessage("Message");
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,input.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ((Button)view).setText(input.getText());
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the help! Still struggling with the language formatting.